# Executing SQL files using Groovy in Gradle

Tags: sql, groovy, gradle

I have a bunch of sql files which I want to execute in my gradle build. I came up with this.

```
def sqlDir = new File('src/main/resources/') 

task testSql << {

    sqlDir.eachDirRecurse() { dir ->
        dir.eachFileMatch(~/.*\.sql$/) {
            //      sql.execute(it.text)
                    println it
            }
    }

}
```

I however, also want to exclude some files, and I can probably do that using if blocks and hardcoding filenames inside the code. Can someone give me a **cleaner solution to exclude files**?

Comment: It seems File trees is the way to go in Gradle, will try it out.

Comment: I didn't noticed, that it was you, who added info in comment. You are moving in right direction, fileTree is the best solution.

Comment: Thank you for confirming Seagull, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you pointed, there is a [[fileTree](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/working_with_files.html)] solution in Gradle

You can use it somehow like that. Please refer link to details.

```
def sqlDir = file 'src/main/resources/' 

task testSql << {
    fileTree(dir: sqlDir, include: "**.sql", exclude: ["somefilename.sql", "otherfilename.sql"]).each {
        sql.execute(it.text)
    }
}
```

Comment: hmajumdar is the OP. ;-)